# JQuery jerky slideUp and slideDown animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, slidetoggle

I have a problem with this animation in jquery, it seems to be jerky with all browser.

This is the link:
[HERE](http://www.pierluigiballatore.com/htsun/servizi.html)

You have to click to "Fotovoltaico" and "Fotovoltaico a concentrazione" for see the animation problem.

Answer (score 5):

It's your margin-top rule, i guarantee it, i've had this before. Add easing to avoid the jerkiness

Comment: Do you have an example of how the OP would accomplish this?

Comment: it doesn't work, I have removed all margin and padding rules.

Comment: body * { 
    margin:0 !important;
    padding:0 !important;
}

Comment: Removing margin-top indeed resolved my slideup jerking animation.

Comment: Removing min-height also resolved it.

Answer (score 4):

As I first suggested below, I have confirmed it is your jquery version...

http://jsfiddle.net/4EKk8/1/

I can prove it by using the above jsfiddle that is just a copy/paste your actual code on the example site.

Simply switching the jsfiddle to use jQuery 1.5.1 from 1.2.6 (your version) fixes the issue.

So... As I said at first.

> First of all you are using jQuery 1.2.6, I would recommend using an updated version.

Comment: Also recommend using an updated version of jQuery. This will make a huge difference in performance (especially from jQuery 1.2.6).

Comment: it doesn't work also with lastest version of JQuery

Comment: Updated answer with potential solution.

Comment: no I actually be sliding the div with class "content" not "slider"

Comment: Yes I understand, I forgot to syntax highlight my example, I want you to try to slide the div with class "slider" instead of "content".

Comment: the problem is that the div "content" has a variable content, so the height is not always the same...

Comment: Updated answer with proof it is your jquery version.

Comment: Look at the source code now, I have updated to Jquery 1.5.1. Is still jerky... What do you think? Anyway, thank you...

Answer (score 3):

I had some jerky animations -- my problem was that I had a `min-height` on the element in the CSS -- removing that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This animations are dependent on the performance of your browser/computer; also how many elements and how much redrawing is required on our page when things are moved around.

Unfortunately there isn't a lot you can do apart from reduce the amount of elements/js on the page.

If it's any consolation, I've been running FF all day and it worked fine for me.

Comment: a little bit of consolation...